# How to update OpenSSL library

Tags: debian, openssl

I'm using Debian (Stretch). Here `openssl version` returns:

OpenSSL **1.1.0f**  25 May 2017 (Library: **OpenSSL 1.1.0-pre6-dev**  xx XXX xxxx)

1. How can I update the "Library" used for OpenSSL (**1.1.0-pre6-dev**) to a most recent version since `apt-get install openssl` does not seem to help?
2. On a different server, `openssl version` returns "OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017)": how is that possible that the version library used is not the same as the package installed?

**Update 1**

`apt-cache policy openssl libssl1.1` output is:

openssl:

```
Installed: 1.1.0f-3+deb9u1
Candidate: 1.1.0f-3+deb9u1

Version table:
1.1.0f-3+deb9u1 500
500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

1.1.0f-3 500
500 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

libssl1.1:

```
Installed: 1.1.0f-5

Candidate: 1.1.0f-5

Version table:

1.1.0f-5 100
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

1.1.0f-3+deb9u1 500
500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 
Packages

1.1.0f-3 500
500 http://debian.mirrors.ovh.net/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

**Update 2**

It appears there are two versions of openssl installed:

`usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl version` returns OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016

`usr/bin/openssl version` returns OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.0-pre6-dev  xx XXX xxxx)

`which openssl` returns /usr/bin/openssl

`ldd $(which openssl)` returns

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff3b074000)
libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f4ec0de0000)
libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f4ec095b000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4ec0757000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4ec053a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4ec019b000)
            /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4ec12f9000)
```

Comment: Why do you want a newer version?

Comment: because it seems to be the reason why I can't compile Nginx from source with http2 module and ssl module

Comment: Are you *sure* you’re using Stretch? What does `apt-cache policy openssl libssl1.1` output? (Please [edit] your question to add the information.) Stretch only has 1.1.0f, but that’s newer than 1.1.0-pre6.

Comment: I just edited the question with the ouput requested, many thanks for your help

Comment: Weird... What do `which openssl` and `ldd $(which openssl)` output? It looks like there’s another version of both the `openssl` tool and the `libssl` library installed.

Comment: You are right, there are two versions of openssl installed, I did not see that coming! I updated the answer with details about this. What should I do from there? try to remove both openssl versions?

Comment: Why are you trying to compile nginx? It's in the repository...

Comment: @Shadur : because I need to compile nginx with the ngx_pagespeed module

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you should remove the locally-installed libraries and binaries (`libcrypto`, `libssl` etc., and `openssl`). This will ensure that you use the packaged versions, which are the ones receiving security support.

To get what you’re *really* after, *i.e.* Nginx with HTTP2 and TLS, I highly recommend you use the [backported package](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch-backports/nginx) instead of building your own; that version has the features you’re looking for. To do so, run (as root)

```
echo deb http://http.debian.net/debian stretch-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
apt update
apt install -t stretch-backports nginx
```

Comment: Dear Stephen, many thanks for your continuous follow up on this issue, your precise answers put me on the right track. Seriously, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Debian Stretch](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianStretch) is the current stable version (as at November 2017). The [security team](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Security) backports security fixes to the released code versions, so while you will not get new features you can be reasonably sure that your SSL libraries are up to date.

What related packages are, or could be, installed

```
dpkg -l '*openssl*'
```

What versions of installed packages are available in the repositories

```
dpkg -l '*openssl*' | awk '/^i/{print $2}' | xargs apt-show-versions -a
```

Ensure everything's up to date

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

For any given package you can see which patches have been applied by reading the Changes file in `/usr/share/doc/{package_name}/changelog.Debian.gz`. For example,

```
zless /usr/share/doc/openssl/changelog.Debian.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using some Linux distro which means your packages updates depend on your distro maintainers and you'll get new versions of packages only when the said maintainers push new versions to your distro repository (it might also involve upgrading to a new version of your distro).

Of course you can follow e.g. [this](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage) manual (if you're on Ubuntu/Debian/Mint) to build a new version of OpenSSL and then use dpkg to install it, but it may lead to dire consequences, for instance your installed applications will either stop connecting using SSL or stop working altogether.

If you absolutely need to have a new version of OpenSSL just to play with, you may compile it from sources and install to /usr/local where it won't interfere with system wide packages. That's usually as simple as running

```
./configure && make && make install
```

But nowadays it's not always straightforward considering the existence of CMake and other build chains. Anyways, a lot of Linux applications come with a manual how to build them.